# Concatenating 4-bit integers

Tags: c++, concatenation, bit-manipulation

I'm using the `cpuid` opcode to retrieve the values of the processor's model and extended model. The docs I'm using say I have to concatenate the value of the extended model to that of the model, and I can get the correct model.

```
Ex. Model:         2h
Model:             Eh
Required Output:   2Eh
```

That is one example, but there are many more like it. How would I concatenate the two numbers together (which are 4-bit unsigned integers) to receive the desired output in C++?

Comment: I think you'd use bit shifting operations.  You could probably also use a union.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shift and add:

```
exModel = 0x2;
model = 0xE;

output = (exModel << 4) + model;
```

Since it was mentioned in the comment above, you could also use a union, but I wouldn't recommend it - it makes the code pretty nonportable (and I think violates strict aliasing rules):

```
union myUnion
{
    unsigned char output;
    struct
    {
        unsigned char model   : 4; // the order of these two fields
        unsigned char exModel : 4; // is system dependent
    };
};

union myUnion u;

u.exModel = 0x2;
u.model = 0xE;

output = u.output;
```

Comment: Writing to one union field then reading from another violates strict aliasing rules.

Comment: @ildjarn: Except when using `char` variants, I think. (Definitely okay with `char`, just not sure about explicitly (un)signed versions). It's okay in the same way it's fine view a standard-layout class-type as a sequence of bytes.

Comment: @GManNickG : Ah, I used the wrong wording. The real problem is that (as per §9.6/1) the allocation and alignment of bit-fields are implementation-defined, but the answer already has that covered ("nonportable"). :-]

Comment: Yeah, I certainly wouldn't recommend doing it that way, but I felt compelled to try it, since there's an answer there that says "Union - no".

Comment: Getting CPUID tends to be pretty compiler/processor specific in the first place, so I'm not sure that makes a huge difference if the rest of the code is or isn't. But shift is easy (and that's almost certainly what the compiler wil do too)

Comment: Re. union - I didn't mean "impossible".  I just meant "Stupid - don't even think about it ;)".  FYI, I kind of prefer "|" over "+"... but I can't think of any reason it matters one way or the other.  IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

Shift - yes.

Union - no.

Example:

```
unsigned char ex_model = 0x2;
unsigned char model = 0xe;
unsigned int i = (ex_model << 4) | model;
```

Comment: You can use a union with a bitfield structure inside.  It would look like hell and be nonportable, but it would (probably) work.